# I have enabled PLACES API in google console and registered my App with SHA key but still I am getting error to enable Places Api

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I have enabled my Places Api from Google console but still I am getting this error which is very confusing for me because I have already registered my App with a valid SHA key in google console

**LOGCAT**

```
2019-02-26 14:35:20.656 3117-5457/? E/Volley: [99] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/placesandroid/v1/search?key=AIzaSyBNUMbFciCO_-Mu7NAGeEKMAho5tY9tzFE
2019-02-26 14:35:20.660 3117-23184/? E/Places: Places API for Android does not seem to be enabled for your app. See https://developers.google.com/places/android/signup for more details.
```

Comment: You must enable Places API from developer console.

Comment: I have already enabled it please read my question carefully

Comment: Your service working well see https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&fields=name,rating,formatted_phone_number&key=AIzaSyBNUMbFciCO_-Mu7NAGeEKMAho5tY9tzFE

Comment: for use the Place api u must enable the billing account..

Comment: billing is also done,,but why it is showing this erro?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to file a support case for this one as it requires investigating your credentials.

File it via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Although my suggestion is that you double check if your API key is the correct one as it may be returning that error due to an invalid API key.

Comment: You may also check if you have already included the release certificate aside from the debug certificate in the API key restriction if the app is in deployment.